Bazel Function to return sha256sum
I am looking a way to find sha256sum in bazel.
I have defined rule, but bazel rule defines output which is written to file.
    # Create actions to generate the three output files.
    # Actions are run only when the corresponding file is requested.

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.sha256],
        inputs = [ctx.file.src],
        use_default_shell_env = True,
        command = "sha256sum {} > {}".format(ctx.file.src.path, ctx.outputs.sha256.path),
    )

    # By default (if you run `bazel build` on this target, or if you use it as a
    # source of another target), only the sha256 is computed.
    return DefaultInfo(files = depset([ctx.outputs.sha256]))


_hashes = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
        "sha256": attr.output(),
    },
)

How can I create a function/macro which returns sha256 of given source?
Appreciate help?

Can you clarify the problem? You should be able to use the rule you've provided to generate an output file which contains the correct hash.
If you don't want to provide an output file, use ctx.actions.declare_file instead. Bazel example:  https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/main/rules/shell_command/rules.bzl

Hi, instead of writing to file, I want to write to string and return it. @SvetoslavTsenov

AFAIK there's no way to do that in Bazel yet. Calling run_shell or even run will always return None and an output file is always required. There's currently an open issue that matches your needs.

Yes, I know it :)  but wanted to check if there is workaround.

This doesn't work as presumed and cannot be done (by design). The return of a rule implementation specifies providers emitted by the rule. This information is used during analysis phase. It does not "return" resulting files. In fact, when this information is being processed, no action has been executed yet, the resulting files don't exist, and hence their digest could not be computed. That (actually running any commands and creating any output) only happens in the next, execution phase.
Essentially, if you want to do something with a hash digest produced by a rule, you'd need to have another rule, whose action would take product of your first rule (file with hash) and perform its action over that. An action taking digest file as input could be put on the action graph and executed when its input becomes available.
I guess the next question in order to determine how, would be: What exactly are you trying to accomplish (do with the computed hash digest)?

Thanks for your suggestion. There is pkg_tar in rules_pkg. It generated a manifest file for example entry looks like  [0,"libxxx.so","bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/application/xxx/src/third_party/xx/libxx.so.stripped","0755",null,null,""], I am looking a way to add sha256sum to it?

It is located at rules_pkg/pkg/private/tar/tar.bzl. I tried using rule but .bzl file do not support invoking another rule.
